# 3 Figures in a column in LaTeX document

Tags: subfig

I am using the following command:

```latex
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=11cm]{bilder/Mode_1_unfolding.png}  
        \caption{Mode-1 unfolding of $\ten{A}$}
        \label{fig:mode1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=11cm]{bilder/Mode_2_unfolding.png}  
        \caption{Mode-2 unfolding of $\ten{A}$}
        \label{fig:mode2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=11cm]{bilder/Mode_3_unfolding.png}  
        \caption{Mode-3 unfolding of $\ten{A}$}
        \label{fig:mode3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{ Unfolding of $\ten{A}$}
    \label{fig:mode}
\end{figure}
```

As a result, I have got:

![resulted pdf][1]

Questions:

1. Why doesn't `\centering` centre the Figure 1.7 in the result?
2. How to add figures with one caption in a column without `subfigure`?

Comment: Could you precise the second question? Why not using subfigures, what's the problem?

Comment: @Janglee --did the answer meet your requirement --was there something else

Comment: @JangLee --did the answer meet your requirement --was there something else

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with minipage/tabular/centering

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Collection of Figures of 2D Phase Portraits} \\ 
\midrule 
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{r.png}
\end{minipage} \\ 
\phantom {}\\
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1.8in]{r.png}\par
\end{minipage}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```